# Error Using Residue: Too Many output arguments

Tags: matlab, math

`[r, p, k] = residue([1, -14],[1,-1,-2] );`

Running the above gives me the correct output.

`[a,b,c,d] = residue([2 -16 40 -42], [1 -11 39 -45]);`

Running the above gives me `Error using residue Too many output arguments.`

Can somebody explain why the first function works but the second function gives me an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize what the problem was. You have to put your output in the form [r, p, k] = residue(a, b).

The answer is in the form:

`b = [2 -16 40 -42]; a = [1 -11 39 -45]; [r, p, k] = residue(b,a);`